# Setting CDI conversation timeout globally

Tags: jsf, weblogic, cdi, weld

Is it possible to set conversation timeout globally for all conversation objects injected into @Named beans?

I have several @ConversationScoped beans, e.g.:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class SomeBean1 {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        if (conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.begin();
        }
    }
}

@Named
@ConversationScoped
public class SomeBean2 {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        if (conversation.isTransient()) {
            conversation.begin();
        }
    }
}
```

The default timeout for these conversations is 600000 ms. I want to know if there is any way to set conversations' timeouts globally or I need to set it in each bean by

```
if (!conversation.isTrainsient()) {
    conversation.setTimeout(MY_CUSTOM_TIMEOUT);
}
```

(the problem is that there is a lot of CDI beans and setting timeout manually in each of them is not the best solution)

Comment: As some of the answers below have demonstrated, there isn't a standard way of doing it. Anything you do (short of stasal's answer) is not going to be portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is the solution I used (Oracle WebLogic 12c, WELD 1.1.Final):

```
import org.jboss.weld.context.http.HttpConversationContext;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Inject
    private HttpConversationContext conversationContext;

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        if (conversationContext != null) {
            final long DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
            if (conversationContext.getDefaultTimeout() < DEFAULT_TIMEOUT){
                conversationContext.setDefaultTimeout(DEFAULT_TIMEOUT);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {}
}
```

Context is injected into the listener and the timeout is set when user starts the session.

Comment: When is sessionCreated called? Should this class be configured in web.xml?

Comment: The sessionCreated method is called when new client session is created. This class should be either configured in web.xml descriptor or annotated as in the code example above (but "metadata-complete" attribute in web.xml should be omitted or equal to "false"). More about hadling servlet lifecycle events is written here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets002.htm#BNAFJ

Answer (score 2):

With Seam/Weld you should be able to do something like the following:

```
@Inject
private HttpConversationContext conversationContext;

public void observePreload(@Observes PreloadCompleteEvent event) {
    //Set global conversation timout to 60000 ms
    conversationContext.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
}
```

Otherwise I believe you will have to set it for each conversation.

EDIT: Note I used a custom event, the same can be accomplished with:

```
public void observePreload(@Observes @Started WebApplication webapp) {
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, implemented this in same way, will post the solution now:)

Comment: What is `PreloadCompleteEvent`? Couldn't find anything about it in the (Weld 2.x) documentation. Thus, I use a similar observer method:  

`public void observeAppInit(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) Object event)`  

and do the work inside this method, which works as suggested.

Comment: PreloadCompleteEvent is a custom event, to use a default you could also do `public void observePreload(@Observes @Started WebApplication webapp) {` or what you have suggested

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done in a portable manner with CDI 1.1.

```
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.ConversationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Initialized;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;

public class ConversationTimeoutDefaultSetter {

    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation;

    public void conversationInitialized(
            @Observes @Initialized(ConversationScoped.class)
            ServletRequest payload) {
        conversation.setTimeout(1800000L); // 30 minutes
    }

}
```

Another portable option would be to decorate conversation. (Warning: untested.)

```
import static javax.interceptor.Interceptor.Priority.APPLICATION;

import javax.annotation.Priority;
import javax.decorator.Decorator;
import javax.decorator.Delegate;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Decorator
@Priority(APPLICATION)
public class ConversationTimeoutDefaultSetter implements Conversation, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    @Delegate
    private Conversation delegate;

    private void setDefaultTimeout() {
        delegate.setTimeout(1800000L); // 30 minutes
    }

    @Override
    public void begin() {
        setDefaultTimeout();
        delegate.begin();
    }

    @Override
    public void begin(String id) {
        setDefaultTimeout();
        delegate.begin(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void end() {
        delegate.end();
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return delegate.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public long getTimeout() {
        return delegate.getTimeout();
    }

    @Override
    public void setTimeout(long milliseconds) {
        delegate.setTimeout(milliseconds);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTransient() {
        return delegate.isTransient();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should've listed the imports for better understanding I think. javax.enterprise.context.Initialized is a part of java-ee-api 7, but we, for example, use java-ee 6, so the only way is to depend on jboss cdi-api which is more portable than my solution but still not 100% I guess

Comment: @stasal, yes, CDI 1.1 is actually required for this. I amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also synchronize the timeout of your conversation bean with the session timeout of your current http request:

```
if (conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.setTimeout(((HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                .getRequest()).getSession().getMaxInactiveInterval()*1000);
        conversation.begin();
    }
```